# Unable to Install Python Packages via pip: SSL certificate verification failed

Tags: python

I am experiencing difficulties installing Python packages using pip on my machine. Whenever I try to install a package, I encounter the following error message: "SSL certificate verification failed." This issue prevents me from successfully installing any packages through pip.

I have already tried upgrading pip to the latest version using the command pip install --upgrade pip, but the problem persists.
I also attempted to bypass SSL verification by using the --trusted-host flag with the pip install command, but it didn't resolve the issue either.
I am running Python 3.9 on Windows 10, and this problem occurs regardless of the package I try to install. How can I resolve the SSL certificate verification error and install Python packages successfully using pip?

Comment: I think that this is the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi